# XCode 7 - How to rearrange source code elements

Tags: xcode, swift, organization, outline-view

I want to ask you if there is any code arrangement functionality in XCode 7+?

I ran into a situation where I want to make my code more readable and organized. For this I have to (re-)sort some functions and elements (Swift) inside some source code files.

Being also an Eclipse and IntelliJ user I am used to have a couple of options, like rules-based auto-sorting or an outline view where I can move functions etc. around. Haven't seen something like this in XCode so far - sure, there is an "outline view" (aka. Symbol Navigator), but it is really only a viewer. -.-

I also know about the CMD+Opt+[ / ] shortcuts but this kind of manual sorting is tedious.

Is there a better way? Thank you.

Martin

Answer (score 0):

As of *Xcode 7.3*, there is no better way of doing what you want. As an *IntelliJ* user, you may want to try *AppCode* by *JetBrains*.